# T4 Code Generator How To Use Web References

Tags: c#, web-services, code-generation, t4

I am creating a Code Generator that will go through each Web Methods of my API (asmx Web Service) but I cannot figure out how to reference the Web Reference in the .tt file

```
<#@ assembly Name="MyApi" #>
```

will not work

```
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'MyApi' could not be found
```

Currently my work around is to create a .dll from my WSDL and I can reference that in .tt with no problem:

```
<#@ Assembly Name="c:\MyApi.dll" #>
```

Is there a way I reference my Web References directly from T4 without having to make .dll s out of them?

Comment: did you mean to reference the wsdl in the generator or in the generated code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly(easily anyhow) reference the current project's files in the T4 generator. To do so you have to use `System.Reflection`, or `EnvDte`

unless you want to access the file directly not as a `reference` but as a text file... then you can have `System.IO` read the file via a relative path.